# Избавится от css calc() в коде

Tags: вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать [такую](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/4v6Er/) ссылку. Ссылка состоит из двух частей - имени и возраста. Длина имени может быть любой, а возраста статическая. Длина самой ссылки может изменятся динамически. Надо сделать так, что б возраст отображался всегда, а имя, если сильно длинное, обрезалось и заканчивалось тремя точками (`overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;`). Реализовать это у меня получилось только используя функцию calc. Она меня смущает тем, что сейчас она в черновиках. Как можно добиться такого же результата без calc()?

Comment: @alvoro, вы на IE8 расчитываете? Если нет, то используйте calc() на здоровье, браузеры достаточно нормально [поддерживают этот метод][1].

   [1]:http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: ну calc() ввели не просто так, до его введения подобные вещи делались на js. поищите полифил.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем от него избавляться? Есть [Myth](http://www.myth.io/)

Comment: Просто интересно, а во что он конвертит конструкции вроде 'top: calc(100% - 10px);'?

Comment: Я бы сказал что top: 100%; margin-top: -10px; но не проверял

Comment: @donkey, нет. Такой код

    body {
      width: calc(100px - 5px);
    }

myth преобразует просто в `width: 95px`, а код

    body {
      width: calc(100% - 5px);
    }

оставит без изменений. Инструмент интересный, но в данном случае бесполезный.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же можно. Для этого используйте свойство max-width.

```
a > .name {
  max-width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: вроде поддержка у `max-width` и `calc` с одних и тех же версий браузеров. То есть, если `calc` уже работает - смысл его менять на `max-width`, а если еще не поддерживается, то скорее всего и `max-width` также не будет поддерживаться

Comment: @Grundy чтобы не использовать такие понятия как "вроде", настоятельно вам рекомендую проверять ваши теории на сайте http://caniuse.com

Comment: На нем как раз указаны одинаковые версии, за исключением `Opera Mini` [calc](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) [max-width](http://caniuse.com/#search=max-width)

Comment: @Grundy и Android.

Comment: @Grundy вообщк-то я погорячился. Там бред какой-то написан. Вот http://htmlbook.ru/css/max-width

Comment: @Grundy max-width еще из CSS 2 доступен, тогда как calc() - только из CSS 3. Ясное дело, что поддержка max-width будет глобальней.

Comment: [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width), [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) - кажется адекватнее, но за исключением IE (7 для max-width, и 9 для calc) - не большая разница по внедрению

Comment: @Grundy поддержка calc() не такая обширная http://htmlbook.ru/css/calc. Тем более вопрос был именно в том, как решить задачу без calc()

Comment: Все зависит от сайта проверки, и тут я больше склонен доверять mdn, чем htmlbook :)

Comment: @Grundy а я больше склонен доверять собственному опыту. Я верстал еще к IE 7.

Comment: так там и написано, что разница только в IE 7-9, так же не исключено. что до этого было доступно с вендорными префиксами

Comment: @Grundy вы не там смотрите. На caniuse указаны современные браузеры в первую очередь. Если вы переключите вкладку то увидите список всех браузеров.